# SSRS access for AD-trust *groups* not working

Tags: permissions, ssrs

I have the following setup:
AD domain "developer.local" has a two way external non-transitive trust with AD domain "customer.local".  There is a 2014 SQL Report server in the developer.local domain.

If I assign SSRS permissions to a group from customer.local, group members receive a "does not have required permissions" when logging in the the SSRS WebUI.  If I assign permissions to individual users then it seems to work.

Is this not a supported scenario, or what should I check to get this resolved?

Comment: What permissions did you grant the user? Did you grant it to the site or to the folder?

Comment: @whysyn: You can regain full control over your question by requesting your two accounts be merged. [See here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) for instructions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have enough reputation to post comments because I'm new here, but this is resolved for me.

I think the root problem is groups are scoped as "domain local" in the foreign AD but that's probably off topic for here.

I created a new group in the developer.local domain and added users from the customer.local domain as members.  This allows the users to access SSRS as expected.

Comment: Hi, Welcome to the site. You should post an answer in the answer section instead of comments, so you were right to post an answer